# How to add Typing indicator for bot framework in node js for SFB channel

Tags: botframework, bots, azure-bot-service, aws-sdk-nodejs

When bot was fetching the data from web services, that time i need to say bot is typing to the users.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the **Typing Indicator** is implemented inside a **Middleware Function** [(Documentation here)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-intercept-messages?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) in Bot Builder SDK.

A middleware basically intercepts all messages that are exchanged between user and bot. For each message that is intercepted, you may choose to do various functionalities. Rather than implementing in a root dialogue ( or you can say bot.dialog("/") ), the **Best Practice** says to implement inside a middleware.

Code Snippet:

i.  `bot.use(builder.Middleware.sendTyping());`

**Or:**

ii.

```
 bot.use({
    botbuilder: function (session, next) {
        session.send();
        session.sendTyping();
        next();
    }
});
```

Try either of solution i. or ii. Both has the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

Bot Framework's NodeJS SDK has a method to send typing indication to the channels. Don't know what SFB stands for though (I guess its *Skype for Business*).

```
bot.dialog("/", function(session){
  session.sendTyping();
});
```

You can check [channel inspector](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/channel-inspector/channels/SkypeForBusiness?f=Typing&e=example1) to find out which channels support this feature.